# Visual Studio Splitting Build Options By Spaces

Tags: c++, c, build, visual-studio-2015

When building a project I need for encryption, it appears that Visual Studio 2015 is splitting the file locations by spaces or something else. I'm not sure how I'd fix it as I don't even know where the error is being produced from. Here is the output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: libtomcrypt, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Performing Custom Build Tools
1>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'GX' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>cl : Command line warning D9036: use 'EHsc' instead of 'GX'
1>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'GZ' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>cl : Command line warning D9036: use 'RTC1' instead of 'GZ'
1>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/MLd'
1>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/YX'
1>cl : Command line warning D9024: unrecognized source file type 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual', object file assumed
1>cl : Command line warning D9027: source file 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual' ignored
1>cl : Command line warning D9024: unrecognized source file type 'Studio', object file assumed
1>cl : Command line warning D9027: source file 'Studio' ignored
1>  aes.c
1>c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '2015\Projects\libtomcrypt\src\ciphers\aes\aes.c': No such file or directory
1>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'GX' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>cl : Command line warning D9036: use 'EHsc' instead of 'GX'
1>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'GZ' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>cl : Command line warning D9036: use 'RTC1' instead of 'GZ'
1>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/MLd'
1>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/YX'
1>cl : Command line warning D9024: unrecognized source file type 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual', object file assumed
1>cl : Command line warning D9027: source file 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual' ignored
1>cl : Command line warning D9024: unrecognized source file type 'Studio', object file assumed
1>cl : Command line warning D9027: source file 'Studio' ignored
1>  aes.c
1>c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '2015\Projects\libtomcrypt\src\ciphers\aes\aes.c': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Probably some project conversion wizard of this preview beta of product is broken. Send your feedback to Microsoft.

Comment: This comes from the previous century.  Not having double quotes around file paths that contain a space is par for the course.  Storing the project in a directory that has no spaces is the obvious workaround.